# GEE script for hyperparameter tuning for random forest regression with grid search

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest

Is there any script GEE for hyperparameter tuning for random forest regression with grid search?

Here's the code:

```
   // Hyperparameter Tuning

var test = bands.sampleRegions({
  collection: validationData,
  properties: ['volper30'],
  scale: 30,
  tileScale: 16
});


// Tune the numberOfTrees parameter.
var numTreesList = ee.List.sequence(10, 150, 10);

var accuracies = numTreesList.map(function(numTrees) {
  var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(numTrees)
      .train({
        features: training,
        classProperty: 'volper30',
        inputProperties: bands.bandNames()
      });

// Here we are classifying a table instead of an image
  // Classifiers work on both images and tables
  return test
    .classify(classifier)
    .errorMatrix('volper30', 'predicted')
    .accuracy();
});

var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({
  array: ee.Array(accuracies),
  axis: 0,
  xLabels: numTreesList
  }).setOptions({
      title: 'Hyperparameter Tuning for the numberOfTrees Parameters',
      vAxis: {title: 'Validation Accuracy'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Number of Tress', gridlines: {count: 15}}
  });
print(chart)

// Tuning Multiple Parameters
// We can tune many parameters together using
// nested map() functions
// Let's tune 2 parameters
// numTrees and bagFraction 
var numTreesList = ee.List.sequence(10, 150, 10);
var bagFractionList = ee.List.sequence(0.1, 0.9, 0.1);
var minLeafPopList = ee.List.sequence(1,9,1);
var maxNodesList = ee.List.sequence(10,150,10);
var seedList = ee.List.sequence(0,150,0);


var accuracies = numTreesList.map(function(numTrees) {
  bagFractionList.map(function(bagFraction) {
  minLeafPopList.map(function(minLeafPopulation) {
  maxNodesList.map(function(maxNodes) {
return seedList.map(function(seed) {
     var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
       numberOfTrees: numTrees,
       bagFraction: bagFraction,
       minLeafPopulation:minLeafPopulation,
       maxNodes:maxNodes,
       seed:seed 
     })
      .train({
        features: training,
        classProperty: 'volper30',
        inputProperties: bands.bandNames()
      });

    // Here we are classifying a table instead of an image
    // Classifiers work on both images and tables
    var accuracy = test
      .classify(classifier)
      .errorMatrix('volper30', 'predicted')
      .accuracy();
    return ee.Feature(null, {'accuracy': accuracy,
      'numberOfTrees': numTrees,
      'bagFraction': bagFraction,
      'minLeafPopulation':minLeafPopulation,
      'maxNodes':maxNodes,
      'seed':seed
})
  })
}).flatten()
var resultFc = ee.FeatureCollection(accuracies)

// Export the result as CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: resultFc,
  description: 'Multiple_Parameter_Tuning_Results',
  folder: 'earthengine',
  fileNamePrefix: 'hyperparameter_tuning',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'})
```

but turns out the result showing below with no difference
[image: but turns out the result showing below with no difference]